# Are questions regarding System76 hardware allowed?

Tags: discussion, scope

Since [System76](https://www.system76.com/) is the largest vendor for consumer PCs with Ubuntu pre-installed, are questions about their products allowed if they don't concern the OS in particular? That would include

- What usb3 or e-stata drives actually work with their laptops
- What peripherals work with particular system76 machines.
- How/should I upgrade the BIOS?

Comment: It's an interesting question, I want to say no, but I would like to  see what others say regarding this.

Answer (score 10):

I don't see why we wouldn't though your first two questions would probably be out of scope for the site anyway as we're not a "list of things" kind of place.

However "How do I upgrade the BIOS on a Pangolin 12345" sounds awesome to me.

Answer (score 4):

As Jorge mentioned, it would be dependent on what the questions actually relate to.

Hardware related questions are better suited for one of the other sites.  Hardware compatibility as well.

Asking "How do I upgrade the BIOS?" is one of those edge-case questions, it could be on topic, it could be offtopic.  If you specify that you're wanting to update the BIOS via Ubuntu, then it becomes a non-edge-case question and is valid for here.